# Three.js. MeshPhongMaterial has a uniform called diffuse. Why is it is not exposed nor can it be set?

Tags: three.js

In `Three.js` I am looking closely at the `glsl` source for MeshPhongMaterial. I notice the fragment shader relies on a `uniform` named `diffuse`. However there does not appear to be any way to set it. There is also an `uniform` named `color` that can be set and does indeed alter what looks like the diffuse color. Huh?

Is `color` copied to `diffuse` under the hood somehow? Can someone untangle this mystery for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look or search though [the source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) you'll find it's set based on the `color` of the material

For example [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/728f241c896179d7629a38f5d43ce2d85f1db13a/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L1990)

Comment: Ah hah! Hang on. Why is the renderer setting material state. That clearly should be the responsibility of Material and it's sub classes. No? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`MeshPhongMaterial` is not a subclass of `ShaderMaterial` even though they both extend `Material`.

Internally `WebGLRenderer` keeps track of / knows how to deal with two different things:

1. **Any** `ShaderMaterial` **with any uniform.** This means that you can make an exact copy of `MeshPhongMaterial` using `ShaderMaterial` and instead of `myMaterial.color` you'd have `myMaterial.uniforms.color`.
2. "Built-in" materials and their properties. For these, `WebGLRenderer` **is aware of all the possible properties these materials expose**. Gman has pointed out where in the code this happens (one of the places). For each material `WebGLRenderer` internally creates a `ShaderMaterial` but instead of handling it's uniforms like it would with any other such material, it manually keeps track and updates everything.

The built-in materials make little sense, since you can easily pipe `foo.bar` to `foo.uniforms.bar` using getters and setters leaving the renderer to only deal with shader materials.

If you really really want a uniform created for a built in material, you have to wait until the renderer creates them, and you can tap into this process with `material.onBeforeCompile = shader=>{}` (the `shader` object will contain the uniforms).

Comment: Whoa. Many thanks. The head scratching has stopped.

Comment: Mine never stopped lol, i can make no sense out of this design.

Comment: You might find this useful https://medium.com/@pailhead011/extending-three-js-materials-with-glsl-78ea7bbb9270